# Округление в PHP

Tags: php, валидация, округление

Пытаюсь написать html страничку на которой имеется текстовый ввод для переменной y, которой можно присвоить значения от -5 до 5 не включительно, я ограничил его поставив вводимый максимум 6 символов, и всё хорошо, но мой практик на сайте открыл консоль разработчика и там присвоил y значение 4.(9) в периоде и оно не было принято, понимаю, что проблема в том как PHP округляет числа.
Вот мой код на php:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["tableRows"])) $_SESSION["tableRows"] = array();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$x = (float) $_POST["x"];
$y = (float) $_POST["y"];
$r = (float) $_POST["r"];
if ($x == 0 && $y == 0 && $r == 0){

}
if (checkData($x, $y, $r)) {
    $y = round($y,2);
    $coordsStatus = checkCoordinates($x, $y, $r);
    $currentTime = date("H : i : s");
    $benchmarkTime = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
    $benchmarkTime = round($benchmarkTime,7);
    array_push($_SESSION["tableRows"], 
    "<tr>
    <td>$x</td>
    <td>$y</td>
    <td>$r</td>
    <td>$coordsStatus</td>
    <td>$currentTime</td>
    <td>$benchmarkTime</td>
    </tr>");
    echo end($_SESSION['tableRows']);
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    return;
}

function checkData($x, $y, $r) {
    return in_array($x, array(-2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)) &&
        is_numeric($y) && ($y > -5 && $y < 5) &&
        in_array($r, array( 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3));
}

function checkCoordinates($x, $y, $r) {
    if (((abs($x) + abs($y) <= $r) && ($x <= 0) && ($y <= 0)) ||
        (($x >= -$r) && ($y <= $r) && ($x <= 0) && ($y >= 0)) ||
        (($x**2 + $y**2) <= ($r**2) && ($x >= 0) && ($y >= 0))) return "да";
    else return "нет";
}
?>
```

Comment: Я бы не парился. Ну не проходит и не проходит. В чем проблема? 4.9999 проходит проверку. Если кто-то ввел больше девяток, то это его проблемы.

Comment: Зачем что-то округлять? Число 4.9 и число 4.99999999999 входят в указанный интервал...

Comment: *"присвоил y значение 4.(9) в периоде"* --- он прям в таком формате написал? или в виде 4.99999999 ?  .................. *"и оно не было принято"*  --- кем не было принято?

Comment: было введено число 4.99999..... Дело в том, что это моя лабораторная работа, которую проверяет практик, и зо того, что 4.99999.... округляется до 5 валидация не проходит, и мне не могут засчитать лабороторную

Comment: `$y = round($y,2);` - округляет до 2 знаков, у вас даже без консоли при ограничении 6 знаков, если вы введете 4.9999 - все равно не пройдет, т.к. округлится до 5, используйте что-то типа `$y=bcdiv($y, 1, 2)+0;`